# Pl/PgSQL fuzzy Interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Is there any stored procedure already coded in `Pl/PgSQL` for fuzzy interval ? like `few minutes ago`, or `just now` or I need to write that by myself ?

Comment: Do you want to convert a real interval into such a string? If yes, that's nothing you should do in your database!

Comment: Yes that I'le like to do, But why shuoldnt I do it in database ?

Comment: You need to define "fuzzy" in a 100% non-fuzzy way to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there'll be something like this ever, as everybody will have it's own definition for the “fuzzy interval”, as `just now` can be up to `50ms` in OLTP, or up to `30min` in DWH databases.

This will totally depend on your application needs and logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there isn't, but it should be easy to write using the [PL/PgSQL date functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Those are not `PL/pgSQL`, but generic `PostgreSQL` date/time functions, which can be used in also in plpgsql for sure.